# Constraint violation exception while deleting record

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am working on a Spring MVC app. I have two model classes, contact and location.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Contact")
public class ContactModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name="contactid")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int contactId;

    @Column(name="contactname")
    private String contactName;

    @Column(name="contactemail")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="contactphone")
    private String phone;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="locationid")
    private LocationModel locationModel;
}
```

and location model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Location")
public class LocationModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name="locationid")
    @GeneratedValue 
    private int locationId;

    @Column(name="locationname")
    private String locationName;

    @Column(name="locationdesc")
    private String locationDescription;

    @OneToMany
    @Cascade({CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinColumn(name="locationid")
    private List<ContactModel> contactList;
}
```

There can be multiple contacts for a location. When I try to delete location, using:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            LocationModel locationModel = (LocationModel)session.get(LocationModel.class, locationId);
            session.delete(locationModel);
```

Following exception raises:

```
    16:46:03,076 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-9090-1) org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

16:46:03,081 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-9090-1)    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:161)

16:46:03,083 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-9090-1)    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:683)

16:46:03,085 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-9090-1)    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:565)

16:46:03,087 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-9090-1)    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)

16:46:03,090 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-9090-1)    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)

16:46:03,093 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-9090-1)    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478)

16:46:03,097 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-9090-1)    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)

16:46:03,098 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-9090-1)    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)

16:46:03,100 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-9090-1)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)

16:46:03,102 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-9090-1)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:646)
```

I do not want to delete contact if location gets deleted. Rather, in related contact, location id should become 0.

I have following import statements in location model:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
```

As you can see, I have imported some statements from JPA and some from Hibernate. Is this permitted?

Comment: Your mapping is incorrect. The OneToMany must be the inverse of the ManyToOne. It should be `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "locationModel")` and should not have `@JoinColumn`.

Comment: I have used removed @JoinColumn and location deleted fine. But now exception raises when I view contact list.

org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.bizzy.scm.model.LocationModel#26]

Comment: That probably means that your data is incosistent: a contact references a location that does not exist. Fix your data, and add foreign key constraints so that this situation becomes impossible.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? User can create location and use while creating contact, and then can delete location. Can we set location id null in the related contact, while deleting location.

Comment: You have to decide: do you want to leave the contacts there when deleting their location, but with a null location, or do you want to delete the contacts with the location? You set the cascade to REMOVE, so I sassume you want to delete the contacts with the location. The problem is that you're not using remove() (the statard JPA operation), but delete() (the proprietary Hibernate operation). So you need to set the cascade to DELETE: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/CascadeType.html#DELETE.

Comment: How can we leave contacts with null value? I mean how can we prevent contacts from deleting, when we delete location?

Comment: Just don't use any cascade, and make sure to set the location of the location's contacts to null before deleting the location.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dereference ContactModel from LocationModel before deleting location. This has nothing to do with hibernate; it would (and it does) fail with plain SQL as well.

So, omit cascade REMOVE, set contactModel of LocationModal to nulland then delete LocationModel.

Comment: location gets deleted. Then when I open contact list, exception raises, as location of the that id not exist. How can we prevent contacts from being deleted and also set their corresponding location id to null or 0, while delete location? Do we need to run select query to get contacts (for that location) and set their location id to null? Can hibernate do this automatically?

Comment: Can anybody please help?

Comment: There are several ways of doing that. Either select all contacts and update as you say but that might not be the most performant solution. Other option is through hql; e.g. `update contact set location = NULL where location.id = 123`